# Https without www redirect to https WITH www

Tags: apache, redirect, https, virtualhost

We are currently struggling with a certificate issue.

We have a certificate for https://www.example.com/ that is working just fine.
The thing that isn't on the certificate is https://example.com.
So the domain without the https.

in the vhost we have this

```
<VirtualHost *:443>     
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com

  etc.
</VirtualHost>
```

We also redirected the http to https://www.example.com.

Thing is when we type in the browser https://example.com it gives us an certificate error and doesn't redirect to the side with WWW.

Do you guys have any idea's how we can fix this issue ?

if you need more info let me know.

Cheers

Comment: Server configuration issues are for serverfault.com, not here.

Comment: It has nothing to do with feelings. It has to do with the purpose outlined in the section you were linked to when you signed up for SO and to the right of the question when you asked it. SO is not "general purpose" as you think. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: the day i signed up is LONG ago XD but ok thanks for the info.